# how does unity handle image scaling

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Unlike in android SDKs, in almost all tutorials I've seen, creating UI elements like menus in unity starts with laying out a default background image onto a canvas object.

I don't really get the fact that different resolution image are not kept in the folder as we do in android(mdpi, xdpi etc.). Is this expected for unity? I mean, the same app can be viewed in a 4K wide screen right? Wouldn't the image appear blurred? How is that handled for apps created by unity? No tutorial I've viewed so far seems to really care for that. Please give me some idea on how this is handled or supposed to be handled in unity 3D.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are making. If it is reasonable to change image resolution based on mobile, you may have to handle that yourself in your game. Unity is a general solution which does not necessarily specialize in UI, though it does have UI abilities.